# Tahoma (MS Shell Dlg 2) font looks squashed in Win7 when created with CreateFont()

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, fonts

I'm trying to use Tahoma font (MS Shell Dlg 2) with a height of -15 and/or height -12 in a Listview control. However with both these sizes, my text appears squashed together horizontally, i.e. l's and i's are so close together you can barely distinguish them. It looks fine with the default height of -13 or with -16.

I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my call to CreateFont, as shown below, or whether this is a limitation of the font?

```
CreateFont(-15, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,    
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, 
    DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, L"MS Shell Dlg 2");
```

I tried playing with the quality and output precision args, with no luck.

Comment: Is the Tahoma font a scalable font or a bitmap font?

Comment: MS Shell Dlg 2 is a logical font, mapped to an [appropriate physical font](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2006/03/18/554308.aspx). Are you sure that physical font is indeed Tahoma? You could try `CreateFont(..., "Tahoma")` for comparison.

Comment: Tahoma is scalable. Yes it's definitely using Tahoma, just tried changing the name, the result is the same.

Comment: Perhaps something has overwritten my Windows Tahoma font? ;)

Answer (score -3):

This was answered by someone on another forum. Apparently there is a bug in a certain version of the Tahoma font.

Comment: Please provide a reference and quote the relevant information in your answer.